# How do I make it so that all filters don't change color when tapped on flutter

Tags: android-layout, flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a template for a filter that takes in one parameter (the tag name) and gets highlighted when tapped. But the problem with this is when one filter is tapped all of them change color because they all use the same boolean value. Sorry, I'm a beginner and I think I'm going about this the wrong way

```
  class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool filterTap = true;
  GestureDetector filterTemplate(String tag) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          filterTap = !filterTap;
        });
      },
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 10.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
            color: filterTap ? Colors.grey : Colors.transparent,
          ),
          child: Text(
            tag,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: filterTap ? Colors.grey[900] : Colors.grey,
              letterSpacing: 2.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all define a StructFilter class with its properties,  For example here is an option:

```
class StructFilter  {
  StructFilter(this.tag,this.filterTap);

  String tag;

  bool filterTap;
}
```

Then collect all of your filter information into a list of StructFilter(i.e `List<StructFilter> filterList`).

For example you can try:

```
Listview(
  children: filterList.map((item){
      return filterTemplate(item);
  }).toList();
)

  GestureDetector filterTemplate(StructFilter structFilter) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          structFilter.filterTap = !structFilter.filterTap;
        });
       },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! This made me understand the steps and did what I wanted to

Answer (score 0):

Use `List` or `Map` or `List<YourClass>` to maintain status of each button.

And try `ChoiceChip`,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Map<String, bool> tagsList = {
    "Tag1": false,
    "Tag2": false,
    "Tag3": false,
    "Tag4": false,
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: tagsList.entries.map((entry) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ChoiceChip(
                label: Text(entry.key),
                selected: entry.value,
                onSelected: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    tagsList[entry.key] = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```